# ESRI HTTP where query

Tags: arcgis-server, rest, json, html

A friend and I are currently creating a pretty straight forward LINQ to ESRI library that sends HTTP queries to an ArcGIS MapServer and then parses the JSON response appropriately.

Everything is currently working beautifully except one thing; multiple Where statements. This seems like a simple syntax issue, but I can't seem to get it working, or find out if it's supported. I'm trying to do something like this.

Doesn't Work:

```
MapServer/22/query?where=MY_FIELD='Whatever'&where=MY_OTHER_FIELD='Whatever'&f=json
```

Does Work:

```
MapServer/22/query?where=MY_FIELD='Whatever'&f=json
```

Also Works:

```
MapServer/22/query?where=MY_OTHER_FIELD='Whatever'&f=json
```

I have tried several different syntax versions, but can't seem to get a multiple Where statement to work. [This is my primary source](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/) for breaking down these queries. If anyone knows the syntax to do this, or knows the source that says it's not possible.

Comment: LINQ to ESRI sounds like a great idea, let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stick to a single where parameter in your query string. Here's an example of a where clause hitting multiple fields:  http://sampleserver3.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/SanFrancisco/311Incidents/MapServer/0/query?geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&where=address%3D%27875+HOWARD+ST%27+or+objectid%3D193510&returnIdsOnly=false&returnGeometry=true&outFields=%27status,objectid%27&f=html

Comment: +1 The [doc](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html) says the where arg can be "Any legal SQL where clause operating on the fields in the layer is allowed." though I suspect there are legal SQL where clauses that aren't supported.

Comment: I can see that happening, since ESRI does not support some clauses on simple IQueryFilters...